# Is specifying a UniqueConstraint on two fields expensive in Django?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

As per the [documentations here,](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) Django conveniently allows you to specifiy a list of fields that must be unique together.

I imagine that for each row inserted in the database Django scans the entire table to verify the constraint. In a table with 1M+ rows I can imagine that this is a nightmare.

Is this indeed how UniqueConstraint operates? **Is it really this expensive?**

Comment: Normally it will create an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: most databases make indexes to make the check of uniqness constraints efficient.

The query to construct this will create an index at the database side. Indeed, if you make a [**`UniqueConstraint`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/db/models/constraints.py#L79), then it will call use the [**`create_sql`** method [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/db/models/constraints.py#L115-L121) to generate SQL queries to create this constraint:

> ```
>     def create_sql(self, model, schema_editor):
>         fields = [model._meta.get_field(field_name).column for field_name in self.fields]
>         condition = self._get_condition_sql(model, schema_editor)
>         return schema_editor._create_unique_sql(
>             model, fields, self.name, condition=condition,
>             deferrable=self.deferrable,
>         )
> ```

This [**`_create_unique_sql`** function [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/db/backends/base/schema.py#L1108-L1137) will, then also check if it has to make an index, given the database supports the `supports_partial_indexes` feature:

> ```
>     def _create_unique_sql(self, model, columns, name=None, condition=None, deferrable=None):
>         if (
>             deferrable and
>             not self.connection.features.supports_deferrable_unique_constraints
>         ):
>             return None
>
>         def create_unique_name(*args, **kwargs):
>             return self.quote_name(self._create_index_name(*args, **kwargs))
>
>         table = Table(model._meta.db_table, self.quote_name)
>         if name is None:
>             name = IndexName(model._meta.db_table, columns, '_uniq', create_unique_name)
>         else:
>             name = self.quote_name(name)
>         columns = Columns(table, columns, self.quote_name)
>         if condition:
>             if not self.connection.features.supports_partial_indexes:
>                 return None
>             sql = self.sql_create_unique_index
>         else:
>             sql = self.sql_create_unique
>         return Statement(
>             sql,
>             table=table,
>             name=name,
>             columns=columns,
>             condition=self._index_condition_sql(condition),
>             deferrable=self._deferrable_constraint_sql(deferrable),
>         )
> ```

This [**`sql_create_unique_index`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/db/backends/base/schema.py#L88) has as value:

> ```
> sql_create_unique_index = "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX %(name)s ON %(table)s (%(columns)s)%(condition)s"
> ```

This thus will create an index, and make lookups fast.

Not all databases however require to *explicitly* make an index. For example, for MySQL, it will create a query that looks like:

```
--
-- Create constraint ij_unique on model foo
--
ALTER TABLE `app_name_foo` ADD CONSTRAINT `ij_unique` UNIQUE (`i`, `j`);
```

But as we can see in the [MySQL documentation on *Creating table indexes keys*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html#create-table-indexes-keys), this will create a database index as well. If we for example inspect the indexes, we see:

```
mysql> show index from app_name_foo;
+--------------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name  | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| app_name_foo |          0 | PRIMARY   |            1 | id          | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| app_name_foo |          0 | ij_unique |            1 | i           | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| app_name_foo |          0 | ij_unique |            2 | j           | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```